# DatePicker Ant Design - add a mask to the manually entered date

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, antd

I would like to share with you a problem I was having while using the DatePicker component from Ant Design - React.

The first challenge was to add a mask to the manually entered date in the input field.

The second challenge was to accept changes in the input without having to press the date confirmation button.

Answer (score 1):

Both issues were resolved as follows:

public/index.html

```html
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- jquery-mask -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<!-- mask formatter -->
<script>
  jQuery(function($){
    $('form').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
      $('.ant-picker-input').find('input').attr('maxlength', '10').mask('99/99/9999');
    });

    $('.ant-picker-input').find('input').attr('maxlength', '10').mask('99/99/9999');
  });
</script>
```

And finally:

```
<Form.Item
  label="Data de nascimento"
  name="birthDate">
     <DatePicker style={{width: '100%'}} format="DD/MM/YYYY" onBlur={(date) =>{
     const currentFormInitialValues = form.getFieldsValue();                                      
     currentFormInitialValues.birthDate = dayjs(date.target.value, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
                                            
     if(!date.target.value || date.target.value === ''){
        return
     }else{                                              
        form.setFieldsValue(currentFormInitialValues);
     };
 }}/>
</Form.Item>
```

It may not be the best way to solve the problem, but it worked. I'm open to suggestions if anyone has a better idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an array of accepted date formats

```
const dateFormatList = [
  'DD/MM/YYYY',
  'DD/MM/YY',
  'DD-MM-YYYY',
  'DD-MM-YY',
  'DDMMYYYY',
  'DDMMYY'
]
```

And assign it to DatePicker format:

```
<DatePicker
  mode={ 'date' }
  format={ dateFormatList }
/>
```

Now if you type only numbers in your date field and press `enter` the date will be formated to the first format available in your array.

Comment: but the intention was precisely to remove the requirement to press enter or click the confirmation button.